# How to compare paths along a x, y coordinate with z being tolerance

Tags: postgis

Bear with me on this explanation... does anyone have some example code that would compare the similarity of two paths along an x, y coordinate system where z is the tolerance setting of 0-100%?

For example, comparing path

```
(0,0,0),(1,1,0),(2,2,100)
```

to path

```
(0,0,0),(1,1,0),(3,3,100)
```

would show 100% similarity because the first two points match on a zero tolerance setting and the last points don't match on a 100% tolerance setting.

and comparing path

```
(0,0,0),(1,1,0),(2,2,0)
```

to path

```
(0,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,0)
```

would show a 66% match because the last points don't match on a zero tolerance setting. Could this be indexable as well?

Comment: Does each linestring always have the same number of coordinates? Or could be they be different, and interpolated in between? What happens if the other coordinate has a different tolerance? How do you quantify similarity of coordinates? In short, no there is nothing out there to do this that I'm aware of, but it can be done within a PL/pgSQL function using linear referencing functions. It should be implemented using the 'M' coordinate, e.g. `LINESTRING M(0 0 0, 1 1 0, 2 2 100)`

Comment: No, each linestring could have a different number of coordinates. If the other coordinate has a different tolerance, it would use an average of both. Bummer, there's nothing that could do this. A PL/pgSQL function would probably not work because I would definitely need an index for 20M+ values. Ill look into the 'M' coordinate.

Comment: You can add a 'M' coordinate to any 2/3D linestring. ST_AddMeasure uses a start and end value, with inner coordinates linearly interpolated, e.g.  `SELECT ST_AsText(ST_AddMeasure('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 2 2)', 0, 100));`. Be aware that the M-coordinate is not supported in most other software like GDAL/OGR. But it is used by Shapefiles and by ArcGIS. If you need to use GDAL or OGR, you may want to stick with your initial idea of using the 'Z' coordinate, since this is well supported by most software.

Comment: You might be about to use a CTE along with generate_series, st_pointn to align the two lines, and then a window function to compare the similarities, if you want to avoid plpgsql.

Comment: @JohnBarça `ST_Dump` returns geometry along with it's index so it probably will be easier to use it rather than generate_series + st_pointn.

Comment: @JakubKania. Doh, true, same idea though.

Comment: @JohnBarça I haven't thought about the idea itself, the question lacks too much info for me. I just wanted to comment about the functions :)

Comment: @JakubKania. I use ST_Dump all the time, I should know better. Ask for clarification then, it has potential to be an interesting question :-)

Comment: Do you want to compare linestring or sets of points? How exactly the order matters? What's the point of this comparison?